# how to show progress bar while loading google map and adding markeres

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, google-maps-android-api-2

i have integrated a Google map in my android application but it takes time to load map completely and place markers.

What i wanna do is that to show progress bar until map is loaded fully and than place markers on it and at last dismiss the progress Bar.

I have used asynctask for this but gives me an error ***not in main thread*** .
So please tell me how to this its very important for me.

Comment: What error did you got? show us the log

Comment: @nayoso not in main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask has two functions - `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()`. You need to make your ProgressBar visible inside `onPreExecute()` and make it invisible inside `onPostExecute()`.

You should not put any UI code inside `doInBackground()` as code inside `doInBackground()` runs on a separate thread than UI and Activity will not let the views to be altered from other threads than UI.

Comment: Okay. is there any other way to show progress bar while doing all this process?

Comment: Yes progress bar will be visible while you are doing this. `onPreExecute()` gets called before `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()` gets called after `doInBackground()`. So your progress bar will be visible through out the whole process and will go invisible when you done doing whatever you want to do inside `doInBackground()`